# Method to turn all values of 3 different arrays into their absolute values and return all 3 keeps only turning the first array but not the next two

Tags: java, arrays, loops, math, absolute-value

I have this assignment for a class that basically gives me three different arrays, and the main method calls my method calls makeThemAllPostive which takes an array and prints out all the values in their absolute value form. However, my method only returns the first array that is called and ignores the next two arrays that call my method.

I have no clue what else to try, I've tried adjusting my for-loops so I can try to calculate the absolute value a different way, or adding more for-loops to try to do each array, and nothing works.

here is the main method part that calls my method

```
System.out.println("\nmakeThemAllPostive test:");
makeThemAllPostive(array1);
String actual = Arrays.toString(array1);
System.out.println(actual.equals("[2, 42, 1]") ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected [2, 42, 1] but you returned " + actual);
makeThemAllPostive(array2);
actual = Arrays.toString(array2);
System.out.println(actual.equals("[4, 1, 3, 0, 8, 4, 2]") ? "Passed!"
  : "Expected [4, 1, 3, 0, 8, 4, 2] but you returned " + actual);
makeThemAllPostive(array3);
actual = Arrays.toString(array3);
System.out.println(
  actual.equals("[8, 42, 1, 42, 1, 1, 2, 42, 5, 0, 2, 42]") ? "Passed!"
    : "Expected [8, 42, 1, 42, 1, 1, 2, 42, 5, 0, 2, 42] but you returned "
      + actual);
```

here is my method

```
public static void makeThemAllPostive(int[] arr)
  {

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    {
      Math.abs(arr[i]);
    }


  }
```

Here is my output:

makeThemAllPostive test:
Passed!
Expected [4, 1, 3, 0, 8, 4, 2] but you returned [4, -1, -3, 0, 8, -4, 2]
Expected [8, 42, 1, 42, 1, 1, 2, 42, 5, 0, 2, 42] but you returned [-8, 42, 1, 42, -1, 1, -2, 42, -5, 0, 2, 42]

My expected output should be all 3 tests passed, but only the first is passed 
:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious bug in your code is that you  do `Math.abs` but you don't assign that value anywhere so the only effect is just heating the Universe. Try something like this instead:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
{
    arr[i] = Math.abs(arr[i]); // assign abs back!
}
```